# Changing the log rotation cycle

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, log-files

On my Linux/Apache server the access_log logs are rotated so that the logs from the last 5 days are kept (access_log.1, access_log.2, etc.)

How do I change this scheme in order to keep more than 5 days?

Comment: What is the log rotation mechanism used. Is it default log rotation provided by apache or systems logrotate program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual log rotating programme used, my vary from distribution to distribution. On debian (and possibly on other linuxes as well) both naming scheme and retention period are defined in /etc/logrotate.conf and /etc/logrotate.d/apache2

Fiddling with those files should solve your problems.

Answer (score 3):

Please be aware that depends where you are and where you work, rotating (deleting) logs are a serious offense. For PCI/HIPAA compliance (and others) you need to store the logs for at least 6 months/1 year.

My recommendation is to disable rotation completely (generally by removing the files from /etc/logrotate.d ) and forward them to  central location...

*I really hate the default behavior on linux systems to treat logs as not very important.

Answer (score 3):

By default your system will use logrotate, which will rename logs. That can be a good policy for some system logs, but I don't think it's the best option for www logs. One good option for Apache is to use a different logger: [cronolog](http://cronolog.org/) will rotate your logs changing its name and can be configured to do nearly everything you coud do.

There are a lot of articles about how to use and configure cronolog, there are many that will instruct you to modify your Apache configuration file (usually in /etc/httpd/) to get nicer weblogs.

Answer (score 2):

$ man logrotate

And look around the corner of your /etc/logrotate.d directory.